# What happens when return address points to a RETN instruction

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, stack, exploit

In the context of exploit development, I end up with this stack:

```
ESP    5d091399        Return address -- points to a RETN in a DLL
ESP+4  42424242        ASCII 'BBBB' -- labelled "junk" in my tutorial
ESP+8  5209398c        Beginning of ROP chain and shellcode
...
```

In the stack above, the return address has been overwritten with a pointer to a `RETN` instruction in a DLL. The effect of this is that the stack goes from `ESP` to `ESP+8`, where the ROP chain starts.

`ESP+4` is never at the top of the stack, hence it's label "junk" and the fact that it can contain any garbage bytes we want. It will have no effect on the execution of the exploit.

**How does a return address pointing to a RETN result in the top of the stack going from `ESP` to `ESP+8`.**

*(Or why are the four middle bytes unimportant?)*

Note:

The pointer in `ESP` is definitely to a single `RETN` on it's own. It is not preceded by a `POP`.

EDIT:

[This tutorial also shows the "junk" (scroll down a tiny bit until exploit code).](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2010/06/16/exploit-writing-tutorial-part-10-chaining-dep-with-rop-the-rubikstm-cube/#ropversion3)

This is the same context as my other tutorial (which is on paper, can't link)

Comment: Double check that it really points to the `ret` and not to a `pop ebp; ret` for example. This is common end sequence that would indeed remove 4 bytes from the stack before returning. In any case, I don't see the point - why not simply start your own ROP chain right at `ESP`, what's the use of invoking an external `ret`

Comment: @Jester Not in this case, I have some ROPs like `pop ebp; ret` in the ROP chain but this is literally just overwriting the EIP with a pointer to a single `retn`. The exploit works flawlessly, I'm just not sure why. See my link for the exact same kind of exploit (`SetProcessDEPPolicy` with DEP on `XP SP3`). There is also a pointer to a `RETN` in the EIP followed by `AAAA` junk.

Comment: @Jester Absolutely, I couldn't see the point myself but I have two different tutorials that do exactly the same thing, for two different programs: overwrite the EIP with a `RETN` + four bytes of junk + ROP chain

Comment: Is the `retn` of the **current** function  (whose return address you have overwritten) maybe the `retn 4` variant? That would also remove the junk before it even goes to the destination.

Comment: @Jester Can confirm the current function is also a `retn`. Every exploit tutorial I read seems to assume 4 bytes of junk there. This must be a common thing to do with `RETN` pointer. `ESP` always seems to point to "current ESP+8".

Comment: I have debugged the `Easy RM to MP3 Conversion Utility` in the linked tutorial, and sure enough it **does** crash at a `ret 4` (address is `0x0041e9ec`, see for yourself).

Comment: @Jester can see yes, clearly I can't use the trace properly then. Thanks for the help.